# How to handled forget password of form through php?

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap

I have a login form having username, email and password. At the end i have  kept the option of forget password. When user clicked on forget password it should confirm and give them password from database.

Comment: where is code? what have you tried so far?

Comment: Where's your code? Please tell us what you have tried..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ideally when user click on forgot password link and verify his/her identity then system should generate reset password link or generate random password and send it to user's email address.

Comment: yeah but how to do such task through code?

Comment: First the user will get the new password and then match with the database field password. if match the use smtp